# How to extract the WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer into a separate package from the rest of the app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am trying to follow [spring.io's websocket tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/).
Everything worked fine as long as every java file was located in the same package (I managed to have an end-to-end websocket communication).

I tried to extract `GreetingController.java` and `WebSocketConfig.java` classes into another package. The app is then not able to communicate via websocket anymore.

The server's console suggests the `SimpleBrokerMessageHandler` is not started. Here are the logs of the working and non-working versions :

```
com.example.tutorial.Application         : Starting Application on DESKTOP-SOF4KJM with PID 13408
com.example.tutorial.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1485 ms
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
com.example.tutorial.Application         : Started Application in 2.631 seconds (JVM running for 3.04)
```

---

```
com.example.tutorial.Application         : Starting Application on DESKTOP-SOF4KJM with PID 2508
com.example.tutorial.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1509 ms
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
com.example.tutorial.Application         : Started Application in 2.52 seconds (JVM running for 2.873)
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
```

How could I make my SpringBoot app aware of this websocket endpoint in another package, knowing that the `GreetingController` is annotated `@Controller` and de `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`-extending class is annotated `@Configuration` & `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` ?

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class shold be in a top-level package covering all other packages. As it will scan from that packages and all sub packages. If you move stuff outside of this default package you will either need to add `@ComponentScan` for all packages you want to scan or define a config class with `@Bean` methods.

Comment: It is exactly the problem I was facing and the solution to it, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to tell the Spring Boot where to look for Spring components outside the main package. You can use `@ComponentScan` for it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "com.example.package")
public class Example {...}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` is annotated with `@ComponentScan` but it is only valid for subpackages.